# Jquery UI Tabs: Link to next/specific tab from within tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I have the following jquery code implemented:

```
$( "#admitpage" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
$( "#admitpage li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
```

The HTML is similar to this:

```
<div id="admitpage">
    <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="tab-1">
        <p>Tab 1 content</p>
        <a class="next" href="#tab-2">Next</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="tab-2">
        <p>Tab 2 content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the problem is, a.next doesn't work. I guess because it is within a tab already. How do I make it work? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been trying to resolve this for the past hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to attach a click event to that link. Something like

```
  $(".next").click(
    function() {
      var currentIdx = $('#admitpage').tabs('option', 'active');
      $("#admitpage").tabs({
        active: currentIdx + 1
      });
      return false;
    }
  );
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer and/or UP it - if it fixed your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually handle it.

First we should set the `active` tab to the new tab using the [active](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) option, and then call [refresh](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-refresh)

```js
$("#admitpage").tabs().addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");
$("#admitpage li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");
$(".next").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var index = parseInt(this.href.split("#tab-")[1]) - 1;
  $("#admitpage").tabs("option", "active", index).tabs("refresh");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="admitpage">
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tab" id="tab-1">
    <p>Tab 1 content</p>
    <a class="next" href="#tab-2">Next</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab" id="tab-2">
    <p>Tab 2 content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```